# KeyError when setting stylesheet for a QFrame

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following code:

```
frame = QFrame()
frame.setStyleSheet('QFrame { border: 1px solid {0}; background: {1}; }'.format(border, background))
```

But I get the following error: `KeyError: ' border'`

I've tried a ton of variants and cannot get this to work. I am trying to style the QFrame, but not child widgets.

Comment: what is `border` and `background`?

Comment: You need to translate `{` and `}`, this one will work. `'QFrame {{ border: 1px solid {0}; background: {1}; }}'.format(border, background)`

Comment: Any color. For instance `red` for both or `#ff0000`. If I take out the "QFrame" and the curly braces, it works, but applies the styles to child classes

Comment: @Sraw Tried that, same result

Comment: I have edited, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a confusion with a style of using format, which is as follows:

```
"{key}".format(key=some_key)
```

To solve this you must use `{{`,`}}` as shown below:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
frame = QFrame()
border = 6
background = '#ff0000'
frame.setStyleSheet("""QFrame{{ border: 1px solid {0}; background: {1}; }}""".format(border, background))
frame.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I feel stupid now. That fixed the key error. I was so focused on the styles, I stopped thinking about Python strings. However, did not solver my stylesheet problem, as it still applied them to the child objects. I may just have to use the `setObjectName` path

Comment: @steveo225 I think that is another problem, if you show more information I could continue to help, if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct please.

Comment: @steveo225 You could improve your example code by placing child widgets, as well as an image of what you get and want to get.

Comment: @steveo225 Which children widgets you have placed, I have tested with QPushButton, QLineEdit, etc, and the style only affects the QFrame, I can not reproduce your problem

Comment: One of the widgets is a QLabel. I actually did switch gears and make a separate stylesheet file and use object names, and that works perfectly. It has the added advantage of cleaning up the code

Comment: The best thing is to create a .qss and add the style similar to CSS style, in this case the objectName are like the id. :P